# How in Cypress, find a card with a specific text and click on a specific button?

Tags: cypress

Faced with a problem, I want to find the card I need in the list of cards guided by the text, and click in this card on the button.

The idea is that would not go into details of nesting.

Enclosing a screenshot of how it looks like:

[image]

**html structure:**

```
<div class="card">
  <span>name 1</span>
  <button data-test="more-menu"><svg /></button>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <span>name 2</span>
  <button data-test="more-menu"><svg /></button>
</div>
  <span>name 3</span>
  <button data-test="more-menu"><svg /></button>
</div>
```

Would like something like this:

```
    cy.get('data-test=badge').then(($) => {
      cy.wrap($).contains(`${name} ${lastname}`).then(() => {
        cy.wrap($).find('[data-test=moreMenu]')
      })
    })
```

Comment: I usually recommend `.within()` command when there is the same group of elements. It helps you isolate your target element and run your further actions, without any conflict with the others.

Comment: You can answer your own question  using "post answer" instead of editing the solution into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.contains` for this. It gets the DOM element containing the text. And then use `next()` which gets the immediate sibling of the current element, something like this:

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Name 1').next().click()
```

In case you have a nested structure inside your `card` class, you can use first `parent()` which will go to the card parent element and then use `within` to scope the next commands inside the same card class, something like this:

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Name 1').parent('.card').within(() => {
  cy.get('[data-test="more-menu"]').click()
})
```

Now We have used `parent()` once since the `.card` is available one level up from `span`. In case you have more levels you have to add more `parent()`.

Comment: no, i want to click more menu button

Comment: Can you add the html structure to the question.

Comment: yes sure, i updated the main question

Comment: This solves a special case
My implementation is more complicated
I also see a problem with the fact that I might have tomorrow span be nested in a div, and everything will break I would like to not be tied to the selector

Would like something like this

updated the main question 

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment:

```
cy.get('#card').contains(your_name).within(($el) => {
   cy.wrap($el).find('#menu').click()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding [Timur Zakirov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12164957/timur-zakirov)'s answer suited for their case:

```
cy.contains('Name 1')
      .parents('[data-test=badge]')
      .within(() => {
        cy.get('[data-test=badgeMoreMenu]').click()
})
```